# How to use geom_ribbon in ggplot for ribbon plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-ribbon

I have tried ribbon plot in R,but my output is not correct ,Can anyone tell whats the problem with my code,thanks in advance
[Output for ribbon plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZ7Ir.png)

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
library(tidyverse)
data = read.csv("Kolkata1.csv")
Dates = as.Date(data$X0)
data %>%  
select(X0, Rain1,Rain2) %>%
filter(as.Date("2001-01-01") > as.Date(X0)) %>% 
pivot_longer(!X0) %>%
group_by(X0) %>%
summarise(mean = mean(value, na.rm = T), sd = sd(value, na.rm= T),
high = mean(value, na.rm = T) + 0.2 * sd(value, na.rm= T),
low  = mean(value, na.rm = T) - 0.2 * sd(value, na.rm= T)) %>%
ggplot() +
geom_point(aes(as.Date(X0), mean), size = 3) +
geom_line(aes(as.Date(X0), mean), size = 1.1) +
geom_ribbon(aes(x = as.Date(X0), ymax = high, ymin = low),fill = "steelblue2", alpha = 1)+
theme_bw()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You need to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your data. Taking the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) can be helpful as well.

Comment: If you want to create a sample data using your 'Kolkata1.csv' file, read the file and subset few rows. `sub_kol <- kolkata[1:10, ]` and then do `dput(sub_kol)` and provide the output in the question so that we can work with sample data

Comment: Dates         Rain1         Rain2
2000-06-01 0.0                 0.0
2000-06-02 0.0                 0.000915518
2000-06-03 0.010818571 0.054956574
2000-06-04 12.117377 21.044977
2000-06-05 8.627044 11.062859
2000-06-06 10.958633 6.822417
2000-06-07 0.71884006 0.54492664
2000-06-08 13.484469 11.522052
2000-06-09 1.8801045 0.0695598
2000-06-10 14.092169 11.4799595
2000-06-11 25.222025 20.209724

Comment: These are values from first 10 rows!